# При запуске MinGW получаю ошибку: "gcc" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: mingw

Решил изучать программирование. Выбор остановил на Си. Уже определился какую литературу читать и в каком векторе обучаться. Как редактор выбрал Sublime Text 3. Установил на комп MinGW. Но вот как с ним работать в консоли никак не разберусь. Кто-нибудь может просветить по этому вопросу?

MinGW установил через MinGW Installer. При установке выбрал пакеты MinGW (C compilation) и MSYS. В cmd.exe вбиваю команды компилятора на компиляцию кода, но мне выдается ошибка отсутствия данных команд. Путь в среде я прописал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю так:

```
C:\Users\exe-cute-er>gcc --version
```

Получаю ошибку

> "gcc" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42790/discussion-on-question-by-exe-cute-er---mingw---gcc-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Много есть туториалов по этому поводу. Попробую описать процесс:

1. Пройди по пути: *Пуск - Компьютер - Свойства - Переменные среды - Переменные среды пользователя для ... - Path* и тут пропишите путь до компилятора
   [image: пример моего пути]
2. Для использования компиляции в консоли вводится команда *gcc имя файла*. Но не забудьте сменить директорию(см. в интернете консольная команда для смены директории). 
   Вы получите скомпилированный файл.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нет в верхнем поле переменной Path. Создайте ее, и запишите путь туда. А не в новой переменной MinGW. Я так же в ответе указывал, что надо прописать в Path

Comment: Команды консоли - http://ab57.ru/cmdlist.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылку.